# Strange characters after extension creating zip file in php - IIS

Tags: php, iis, php-ziparchive

After moving a website from one server to another, both running IIS, when a zip file creation script is called the file created has some random characters at the end, ex. what should be 'test.zip' is  converted to 'test.zip08c1b35d'   giving error when trying to download them.
I've discovered that it only happens inside the website path, if I create a symbolic link inside the website path with the same name, pointing to a folder outside the website path the zip file is created with the correct name. Any other folder within the website path the name is changed.
The zip file format is correct as if I delete the characters and leave the name ending '.zip' the file opens  fine.
The code used is:

```
$dir ='../mylims/test/';
$destination = $dir.'test.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    echo "Error";
}
$zip->addFile('./test/testfile.txt','testfile.txt');
$zip->close();
```

Any suggestions what to look? Tks

Comment: You can use the failed request tracking to view the detailed process, it will show where the extra characters have been added. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85).

Comment: Hey is your problem solved?

Comment: No, the only workaround was to move to Apache.